# Pseudo-Random sequence generator based on seed

Tags: java

I managed to make a random sequence based on a seed, but now i am trying something else. basically, it generates a number(Based on a seed), then checks if that number is already in the array, then if it isn't in the array, it adds it to the array, and if it is, it goes on to the next one. However, my program works fine until it hits a 0, then it just keeps repeating 0. here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a seed(One letter)");
    String input = s.nextLine();
    char a = input.charAt(0);
    int b = ((int) a) - 96;
    Random rnd1 = new Random(b);
    int[] letters = new int[25];
    boolean isSame = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {   
        int c = rnd1.nextInt(26);
        for(int x = 0; x < i; x++)
        {
            if(letters[x] == c)
            {
                isSame = true;
            }
        }   
        if(isSame == false)
        {
            letters[i] = c;
        }
        System.out.println(letters[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: It looks like the condition **(isSame == false)** is not true after several repetition and therefore it just prints out the initial value that is assigned to an int array, which is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Break the problem up in to parts, first a method to test for a `value` in `letters` between indices `0` and `p` like

```
private static boolean match(int[] letters, int p, int val) {
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        if (letters[i] == val) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then a method to `fill` an `int[]` with a provided `Random` to a given `length`. Since you want the `int[]` to be unique, you can use an inner `do while` loop while the next symbol is already present. Like,

```
private static int[] fill(Random rnd1, int length) {
    int[] letters = new int[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int c;
        do {
            c = rnd1.nextInt(length);
        } while (match(letters, i, c));
        letters[i] = c;
    }
    return letters;
}
```

Then you can call that (and you might use `Arrays.toString(int[])`) to output the array like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a seed(One letter)");
    String input = s.nextLine();
    char a = input.charAt(0);
    int b = ((int) a) - 96;
    Random rnd1 = new Random(b);
    int[] letters = fill(rnd1, 26);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters));
}
```

Comment: I'm not very good with methods and functions. I still don't get what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Two quick fixes:

## 1) The for loop is going up to index 25 which is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException as your array is of length 25.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) 
//Your code
 }
```

## 2) Replace this code with something that can satisfy the condition as well generate a new random number and then assign it to array.

```
if (letters[x] == c) {
    isSame = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to shuffle the numbers 0-25, that is, storing each number exactly once, but in a random position in the array. This is also known as generating a random permutation. Assuming this is the case, then there are two problems with your code:

1. `isSame` needs to be set to false when you pick a new random number, otherwise once a number is repeated, `isSame` is true for all subsequent numbers and nothing new is written to the array.
2. When a random number is picked that was already in the array (when isSame is found to be true), a new number needs to be found for that index. In your code, that index is skipped instead, and the value at that index will default to 0.

It is perhaps also worth mentioning that there are more efficient algorithms for this problem. This method will keep picking a lot of random numbers that are then just discarded, which is wasteful. The Fisher-Yates shuffle solves this (pseudocode from wikipedia):

```
for i from 0 to n−2 do
     j ← random integer such that i ≤ j < n
     exchange a[i] and a[j]
```